# How can I tell if there is a trap in my floor drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, smell, diy-vs-pro

I’m a bartender at a restaurant that is in an old gas station building. The floor drain that the sinks behind the bar drain into frequently smells like rancid meat farts, which is quite embarrassing when there are customers in the bar, but my boss has made no effort to try and figure out what the problem is.

I’m no plumber but have surmised that this is an issue with the floor drain either not having a p trap or it being messed up in some way. The trap couldn’t be dry from what I understand because it’s used frequently. I am wondering if there’s a way that this could be fixed that wouldn’t involve jack hammering the cement slab up, if I can determine whether there is a trap or not, etc. Currently I’ve been told to just dump bleach down the drain, which... doesn’t help.

**Edit:**
There’s also an oatey sure vent air admittance valve, if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the air admittance valve? How could it be connected to the floor drain, ALL of its connections are under it, no.?

Comment: The air admittance valve is directly to the right of the floor drain, I’ve attached a clearer picture. That seems like it could be it, but I’m also reading that it’s pretty rare for them to fail? Never thought I’d be this intrigued to learn about plumbing! Thanks

Comment: I have to charge my phone to take a flash picture, lol. But the valve comes straight out of the concrete next to the drain.

Comment: Okay there it is!

Comment: "*Never thought I’d be this intrigued to learn about plumbing!*" Lets put that to the test, unscrew the AAV and stick you nose over the pipe. Wash the AAV and see if the little flapper inside is still spring loaded.

Comment: Nothing horrible will happen if I do so?

Comment: Okay, I didn’t wait for an answer to unscrew it and nothing horrible happened but I don’t know what flap is supposed to be spring loaded?

Comment: There is flap, it only allows air to move in from the top into the pipe but not fumes from the pipe to move out into the room. You could blow and suck on it, if it works you will not be able to blow air through it but when you suck air will pass through into you lungs. That is why i said wash it. Sanitize it with per the serve-safe sanitizing instructions you told your employer you memorized.  Is the pipe stinky without it installed?

Comment: Yea the pipe is stinky, and the valve itself is so nasty I wouldn’t put my mouth on it even if it was soaked in sani for a month. But having stuck a bag over it I think I’ve determined that regardless of if there’s a trap, it is letting air out, so the valve is the culprit? This has been a fun use of a slow shift, thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

The presence of an air admittance valve (AAV) implies a trap (since otherwise there's not a lot of point for a vent), but is *then* also the most likely thing to have failed such that things stink.

It can be replaced, and probably should be.

Comment: "*The presence of an air admittance valve (AAV) implies a trap*"  It does?

Comment: Without a trap, there's no need for a vent, so yes, it does.

Comment: Also, I stuck a plastic bag over the vent and ran the sink and it inflated. Which... is not what’s supposed to happen right?

Comment: The bag should deflate, if anything. Despite the claims you have read, **my experience** of AAVs is that they can be relied upon to fail, and stink, and thus I will go to a lot of effort to provide a vent pipe leading outdoors rather than relying on an AAV.

Comment: "*Without a trap, there's no need for a vent*".    I understood what you said,  i was asking you to explain why that is. **Is it not possible that it is not done correctly**.  Why does a drain without a trap not need proper venting?  The vent does two things provides air intake for  **proper draining** and moves the gasses, *prevented from entering the building by the trap*, to the outside. I am not trying to be argumentative, i want to understand why you say that if it does not have a trap it does not need a vent. Without a trap, Does it not need a vent for proper drainage?

Comment: ...Without a trap, **the drain is the vent, and sewer gas enters the building, since it vents both ways.** The reason you have a vent is to prevent siphoning the trap dry. A properly functioning AAV would let air in to do that, but not let sewer gas out. Bothering to install an AAV *implies* (not guarantees) the installation of a trap. If you were not installing a trap, you'd be a strange shoddy corner-cutting excuse for a plumber to bother installing an AAV.

Comment: So just to see if I understand, the vent letting air out creates positive pressure and siphons the water out of the p trap? And without water in the p trap the gas escapes thru the floor drain. And if there wasn’t a p trap, the vent having failed would let gas out nonetheless. So either way it’s likely the vent? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not exactly. The vent PREVENTS siphoning the trap. Water flows through the trap, but when you stop putting water in, water stops coming out, thus maintaining the trap seal. Without a vent, if enough water flows in to fill the pipe beyond the trap, it siphons the water out of the trap, leaving it dry, which allows sewer gas to flow back through the drain. With a vent, if the pipe beyond the drain fills it starts to pull air **in** through the vent, protecting the trap seal. If the "one way valve" in the AAV fails, sewer gas flows **out** through that, rather than it only allowing air **in.**

Comment: Water flow through a trap should be only by gravity, not by siphoning.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for explaining. So the smell is coming from the vent and would only be able to come from the drain with a vent installed if the vent was stuck shut or something, which I know it’s not because of the bag test. Cool! I think I can make a solid case for a new vent now.

Comment: _"I stuck a plastic bag over the vent and ran the sink and it inflated"._ This is the simple way of proving that the AAV has failed.